# Configure TFS Online "Azure App Service Deploy" Step

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-app-service

We have an ASP.NET Core application build in TFS and we want to deploy the built files to multiple Azure App Services. It appears the solution is to use multiple **Azure App Service Deploy** steps. While testing this we are able to get the output zip copied to the App Service but we can't figure out how to copy all the raw output files. Can anyone help us understand how to do this?

[image]

Comment: What's that mean for "`copy all the raw output files`"? you have already built and published the artifact.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the screenshot you will copy the files from  `$(build.stagingdirectory)` to App Service.

So, if you want to copy other files, then you can add a [`Copy Files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts) task before the `Azure App Service Deploy` step to copy the files to  `$(build.stagingdirectory)` first.

By default, the value of **Package or Folder** is something like

```
$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.zip
```

So, you can try to use `$(build.stagingdirectory)/**` to copy all the files to App Service.

See below articles for more information:

- [How To: Extend your deployments to Azure App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/howto-webdeploy-webapps?view=vsts)
- [Deploy a web app to Azure App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps?view=vsts)